# Github refusing to merge unrelated histories

Tags: github

Me pueden dejar los pasos para conectarme a mi repositorio remoto en github y actualizar todo el codigo que esta en ese repositorio, gracias

```
$ git remote add origin github.com/alexhak1/ThinkSecWEB
fatal: remote origin already exists

$ git push master
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

Comment: Cuéntanos paso a paso qué hiciste, tanto en el remoto como en el local, qué comandos usaste y en qué punto te salió ese error. Yo me imagino dónde se produce, pero no quiero escribir una respuesta basada en supuestos ni tú debieras acostumbrarte a preguntar en forma tan escueta y esperar a que nosotros adivinemos el resto

Comment: Disculpa,  esto es lo que hice pero la verdad no comprendo bien, yo imagino que primero me debo conectar remoto luego ya el git push master, pero no se como hacer eso:

Comment: MacBook-Air-de-Alejandro:Thinksec-2 alexhack$ git remote add origin https://github.com/alexhak1/ThinkSecWEB
fatal: remote origin already exists.

Comment: MacBook-Air-de-Alejandro:Thinksec-2 alexhack$ git push master
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Esos comentarios debieras ponerlos en el contenido de la pregunta. Voy a echarte una mano editando esa parte

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo que usualmente se hace es clonar el repo

```
git clone git@github.com:alexhak1/ThinkSecWEB.git
```

Mediante lo cual se crea la carpeta `ThinkSecWEB` y se configura inmediatamente el remoto `origin`.

Me da la idea de que tú hiciste

```
   git init
   git remote add origin git@github.com:alexhak1/ThinkSecWEB.git
```

Hecho esto, empezaste a crear archivos y carpetas.

Cualquiera de los dos flujos te llevará a que el repetir la segunda instrucción te de error porque el `origin` ya existe

El comando

```
git push master
```

Siempre dará error, porque la sintaxis debiera ser

```
git push origin master
```

Que significa "has un merge de mi local master la rama remota origin/master".

Dado el mensaje de error que consta en tu pregunta, supongo que en algún momento le pusiste (por ejemplo):

```
git add --all
git commit -am "primer commit local"
```

Y luego

```
git pull
```

o

```
git push
```

o

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Pero tu remoto tiene un commit que tu local no tiene, y viceversa. No hay un ancestro común y por lo tanto no se puede hacer merge.

Si el código del remoto es ligeramente parecido a tu código local y efectivamente quieres hacer un merge, la solución sería:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --soft origin/master
git add --all
git commit -am "comit encima del primer commit remoto"
git push origin master
```

Si de verdad los códigos no tienen nada que ver, puedes hacer:

```
git push -f --set-upstream origin master
```

Y con eso vas a pisar el remoto forzadamente con tus commits locales. Ojo que con esto se perderá lo que hay en el remoto.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando el git bash nos dice: **Github refusing to merge unrelated histories** (Github rechaza unir historias no relacionadas) tal y como dice la pregunta, la Solución que he aplicado, y me ha funcionado es

```
$git push origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Ahora si lo que quiere es hacer merge:

```
$git merge origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

De esta manera, se garantiza que las historias no relacionadas o inconexas (unrelated-histories) puedan ser conectadas al repositorio.

Comment: Por favor explica tu solución

Comment: La explicación en la edición @Aprendiz

Answer (score 1):

Según veo tu problema es que no estás especificando el `upstream' a dónde enviar los cambios

```
$ git push origin master
```

Ahora según el error en la descripción es probable que la historia difiera por lo que puedes forzar el push

```
$ git push origin master --force
```

Aunque lo mejor sería hacer un merge de 3way y después subir los cambios

```
$ git pull origin master
$ git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución es:

```
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
```

y luego

```
git push
```

Comment: Una explicación al código en las respuestas eleva su calidad y siempre es bien visto

Answer (score 0):

Pasa que cuando quieres agregar un repositorio remoto a tu repositorio local los dos repositorios tienen historias diferentes y por eso no permite hacer merge y para que los dos puedan hacer merge usa este comando:

```
git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories
```